# While loop to Array conversion

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Having an issue with a piece of code when trying to pull an array out of a while loop. The code is as follows

```
$query = "SELECT ID,Assigned_user FROM work_orders";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $Assigned[] = $row['Assigned_user'];
    $ID[] = $row['ID'];

    var_dump($ID);
```

The issue is when `var_dump()` returns its results the `$ID[]` is split in to two arrays which look like the following

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string '2' (length=1)
D:\wamp64\www\MYCMS\Admin\test.php:31:
array (size=2)
  0 => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => string '3' (length=1)
```

Where i need it to be one array which consists of the two values like `Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 )`

then i need to explode it like

`$IDS = explode(",", $ID);`

so it becomes a string "2,3" so it can be used in the IN statement

to insert in to a select statement from my database

`$wo_request = "SELECT * from work_orders Where ID IN ('$ID')";`

if anyone can guide me on how to do this i would really appreciate it.

P.S I cant str_split it either since this needs to work for a whole load of numbers that go in to the hundreds so split it down to one character doesn't work 
            `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have dumped array inside while loop. `var_dump` after while loop then check

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $Assigned[] = $row['Assigned_user'];
    $ID[] = $row['ID'];
} //complete while loop

    var_dump($ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need also:

```
implode(',', $ID);
```

To get "2,3" string, explode does the oposite.

Comment: I was just about to write this :p $wo_request = "SELECT * from work_orders Where ID IN (".implode(",",$ID).")";

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $Assigned[] = $row['Assigned_user'];
    $ID[] = $row['ID'];
}

implode("','",$ID);

$query = sprintf("SELECT * from work_orders Where ID IN ('".$ID."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `$ID` array is only being set so it can be `implode`d into a string, you could achieve the same results using string concatenation.

```
$ID = ''; // Define $ID as a blank string so it can be added to in the loop
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$Assigned[] = $row['Assigned_user'];
$ID .= $row['ID'] . ','; // Append current ID and a comma to the ID string
}
rtrim($ID, ','); // Trim off the last comma
```